# SVN: How to tell what directory your working copy checks out from

Tags: java, svn, ant

I have inherited a web application where the original developer just upped and quit and I'm trying to kick off a release that has zero (none) documentation behind it.

Systems just granted me access to the server (CentOS box) and I am inside the directory that is a working copy of a project inside a SVN repo. I'm at the terminal and trying to figure out how to use `svninfo` to tell me what location inside the repo the current directory is a working copy of.

Is this possible? If not what are my other options? FYI I have terminal access to the working copy, the build.xml Ant script that `svn update`s the working copy and then build the app from it, as well as Eclipse SVN Repositories access to the SVN server itself. I'm just making a rapid transition over from CVS-land and not sure how I can tell what directory the project is checking out from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "svn info ." . is the current directory

Comment: Results: `svn: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'; please get a newer Subversion client` - what is this?!?

Comment: It means that the working copy has been created with a more recent version than the svn command line client. Upgrade the SVN client, or use the same tool than the one that has been used to create the working copy.